# On sequences of rational functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, limits-and-convergence, rational-functions, analytic-continuation

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of rational functions of the following form: $$ f_n(z) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{C_{m,n}}{z-m}$$ with $C_{m,n} \in \mathbb{Z}$, $C_{1,n} = 1$, and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $M(n)$ such that for every $m \geq M(n)$ we have $C_{m,n} = 0$. Suppose that $f_n$ converges uniformly in any open disk of radius $ < 1$ around the origin in the complex plane, and denote by $f \colon D_1(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ the limit.

> Is it necessarily possible to extend $f$ to a holomorphic function on
>   $\mathbb{C} \setminus S$ where $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a (possibly
>   infinite) set of isolated points.

Comment: The answer to the second question is obviously "no": take $C_{1,n}=C_{n,n}=1$ and $C_{m,n}=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev I will have to reconsider this, I will delete it for now. Thanks!

Comment: The (negative) answer is contained in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186587/meromorphic-extension-of-a-function/186590#186590

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I am not sure that I am convinced. Two minor issues are that in my case $\Lambda = \mathbb{N}$ is quite specific since the convergence in my case takes place in the unit disk, and not in another half plane. More importantly, I am ready to take $S$ to be any infinite set of isolated points without specifying any restrictions on the residues (Not necessarily $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$). Moreover, I do not require the rational functions $f_n$ to converge to the continuation of $f$ in any way outside the unit disk.